# error building mobilevlc -> autoconf issue

Tags: vlc, autoconf

When compiling MobileVlc for IOS-Simulator on my MacMini I get the following errors:

I start building MobileVlc using the following command: `./buildMobileVLC.sh -s`

Last output is:

```
mkdir -p -- /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/i686-apple-darwin11/share/aclocal && cd a52dec && autoreconf -fiv -I/Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/i686-apple-darwin11/share/aclocal
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/i686-apple-darwin11/share/aclocal --force 
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
autoreconf: configure.in: tracing
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf --include=/Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/i686-apple-darwin11/share/aclocal --force
**configure.in:74: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_SHARED
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.in:75: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
configure.in:76: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
autoreconf: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1**
make: *** [.a52] Error 1
```

Can somebody help me?

After closer looking at the problem I must say, that the above is always the output of the second try. On the first try I always get this:

```
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/cmake-commands.txt
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/cmake-compatcommands.txt
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/ctest.txt
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/ctest.docbook
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/cpack.txt
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/cpack.docbook
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/ccmake.txt
-- Installing: /Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/doc/cmake-2.8/ccmake.docbook
-- Installing: **/Users/theo/Projects/compile/vlc/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/share/aclocal/cmake.m4**
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:21 --:--:--     0touch .cmake
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:11:00 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:11:10 --:--:--     0^Cmake: *** Deleting file `yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz'
make: *** [yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz] Interrupt: 2
```

The output stops at Installing cmake.m4 never ending. I have to interrupt it with `^C`.

Comment: When building software from a properly constructed tarball, it is not necessary to run autoconf unless you have unpacked the tarball on a drive with clock skew.  (So that, for example, the last modified time on one of the meta files is in the future.)  If your timestamps are good, and you have not unpacked on a network mount, and you have not modified any of the files in the distribution tarball, then there is a packaging error and the tarball is flawed.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is that the build script is trying to run autoconf, which it should not do.  The version of autoconf that you have on your box is different than the version expected.  Do NOT attempt to fix this problem by installing autoconf. You should not need to run autoconf to build the software.  If you need to do so, it is a packaging error and should be reported to the maintainer as a bug.

Comment: Thank you very much! I submitted a bug report in VLC bug tracker.

Comment: I submitted a bug report, but the answer was "worksforme".

Comment: And further:  and my setup "does not compile libtool". That would be the problem. But why does it not compile libtool?

Answer (score 0):

AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL configure.in:76: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL autoreconf:

sudo apt-get install libtool